# HTML select doesn't show scrollbar with size = 1 and multiple = true in Firefox 39

Tags: html, firefox, select

When I create `<select>` element with **multiple** selection and **size=1**, Firefox doesn't draw scrollbar. Firefox version is *39*.
For example, in chrome everything is OK.

```
<select size="1" multiple>
        <option value="0" label="Val1">Val1</option>
        <option value="1" label="Val2">Val2</option>
        <option value="2" label="Val3">Val3</option>
</select>
```

Can I do something with it?

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tzd6uazj/

Answer (score 0):

> When you define `size="1"` you are essentially creating a 1-option-high multiple select box, which of course is an incredibly unfriendly thing to do to your visitors.
>
> If you want to allow users to select multiple list items, set the `size` attribute to a reasonable number so they can actually see more than one option at a time.

Even on chrome(in your fiddle), actually I couldn't see the option 2 in your select....
Can't you use a checkbox button group?

[image]

Comment: The question is not about UI or UX. It's about the browsers' behavior, Firefox behavior, when drawing select element with size=1.
At the moment I don't care about providing the most friendly UI to user. What I'm asking about is "Why Firefox does it and how I can make it draw this scrollbar?"

Comment: try this then <div class="container">
    <select size="1" multiple style="font-size:30pt">
    <option value="0" label="Val1">Val1</option>
    <option value="1" label="Val2">Val2</option>
    <option value="2" label="Val3">Val3</option>
</select>
</div>

you will see that the problem is that the scroll has a minimun size that it's to big...

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=300979

Comment: Changing font-size to 30pt makes scrollbar visible. Maybe there is some other hack, without making too big font?

Comment: The other one that I know refers to setting the height of the select...

<div class="container" >
    <select size="1" multiple style="height:36px;">
    <option value="0" label="Val1">Val1</option>
    <option value="1" label="Val2">Val2</option>
    <option value="2" label="Val3">Val3</option>
</select>
</div>

but then you would have the size=2......... so maybe getting the font sigthly bigger and using the heigh 36 (the minimun for a scrollbar)